# How to fix the error "computed property name must be of type string , number, symbol or any using typescript?

Tags: typescript

i am new to programming and learning typescript on the go.

I have code like below,

```
const initialItems = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (something) {
        return { [nodes[something.index].id]: true}; //error here
    }
}, [something]);
```

in the above code i get error " computed property name must be of type string, number symbol or any.

could someone help me how to fix this thanks.

Comment: what is `something`? what is `nodes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is telling you that the property name in the object you are returning must be either a `string`, `number`, or `symbol`.

So to me this looks like `nodes[something.index].id` is neither of them.

Currently, you only check that `something` exists. That could mean `something.index` does not exist, or `nodes[something.index]` does not exist or the whole thing.

In general, when you ask others questions on SO, try to narrow your problem as much as possible by debugging the issue yourself, so it is easier for us to help you.
Provide more context about the values in your variables for example.

In your case, I would change the code to the following:

```js
const initialItems = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (something) {
        console.log("something", something); 
        console.log("something.index", something.index);
        console.log("[nodes[something.index]", [nodes[something.index]);
        console.log("nodes[something.index].id", nodes[something.index].id); // this needs to be string number or symbol
        return { [nodes[something.index].id]: true}; //error here
    }
}, [something]);
```

And then take a look in the console and see if the values are what you expect them to be (I expect not).